# Microsoft Driver Verifier

Tags: windows, device-driver, wdk

In Verifier Dialog, there is a window to select drivers to verify.

The list control has 4 column.
1. Verify?
2. Driver name.
3. Provider
4. Version

My driver's provider and version are represented as "unknown".
I don't know how can I set these values.

Where can I set this value? By SignTool? Or Resource file?
Yes, this is not a big problem. But I would like to correct that.

Let me know please.
Thanks.

**Edit**:
Our driver has a rc file.
The file defines following values.

VER_FILETYPE
VER_FILESUBTYPE
VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_YEARS
VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR
VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR
VER_COMPANYNAME_STR
VER_PRODUCTVERSION
VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
VER_FILEVERSION
VER_FILEVERSION_STR
VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR
VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR

Windows explorer represents our driver's version and digital sign information well.
But Driver Verifier doesn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=182912 :

**Driver Verifier displays the FileVersion string: it's set from
VER_FILEVERSION_STR in inc/api/common.ver:**

VALUE "FileVersion",     VER_FILEVERSION_STR BUILD_MACHINE_TAG_PADDED

In Vista and Windows 7 the FileVersion string doesn't seem to be
displayed in the Windows Explorer properties window. You can also see
all the version strings by running Sysinternals' sigcheck from
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx .

There's a great template for setting the version information in the thread at http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-device-drivers/262446-how-do-i-set-driver-version-description.html .

Answer (score 2):

Your SOURCES should include a .rc file that should contain a [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28VS.85%29.aspx) resource. If it already doesn't, please add it.

The INX file also contains a [Version] section that will end up in the generated .inf file. Update it to match your VERSIONINFO as needed.